# Using WITH(NOLOCK) Together with FREETEXTTABLE

Tags: sql-server

I'm confused about how to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` along with full-text search.

From [SQL Server NOLOCK and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783525/sql-server-nolock-and-joins) I got an important information that we should use `WITH (NOLOCK)` in each table in a SQL join. However, it doesn't work with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable AS FT_TBL WITH (NOLOCK)
FULL OUTER JOIN
    FREETEXTTABLE (myTable, fieldName,  'SRI') AS KEY_TBL WITH (NOLOCK)
ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

The error message is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

The problem is in the 'AS KEY_TBL WITH (NOLOCK)', because it works without the 'WITH (NOLOCK)' on it. What should I do? I want that every similar record appears in the search result although somebody else updating those records. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Using set transaction isolation level read uncommitted should at least work. I assume you know all the problems related to using read uncommitted / nolock.

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: @JamesZ : Do you mean like this? http://sleepingcoder.blogspot.com/2011/04/control-locking-with-sql-full-text.html

Comment: Why do you think you need NOLOCK? Sounds like another case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have problem X and think Y (NOLOCK) is the answer. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FREETEXTTABLE` doesn't support table hints. If you want uncommitted reads throughout (which is what `NOLOCK` achieves for a single table), set the transaction isolation level before, either in T-SQL:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT * 
FROM myTable AS FT_TBL
FULL OUTER JOIN
    FREETEXTTABLE (myTable, fieldName,  'SRI') AS KEY_TBL
ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

Or in your client code using `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`.

But you should be fully aware of the consequences of this: `READ UNCOMMITTED` will indeed issue fewer locks, but it can give back inconsistent results. If all you're after is reads that don't block, a worthwhile alternative to explore is [snapshot isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tcbchxcb) and the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option. The problems with `NOLOCK` as well as the alternatives are eloquently summed up [in this article](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).